# What is this syntax for in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

`module exmaple(input a, b, input in[2:0], output d, e, output out[5:0])`

I am new to Verilog and trying to understand what `input in[2:0]` means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't valid Verilog(IEEE-1364), it is SystemVerilog(IEEE-1800). SV allows ports to be declared as multi-dimensional arrays so in this case `in` is declared as an array of single bit wires.

Generally if you wanted a vector for a port you would use `input [2:0] in` which is valid in both Verilog and SystemVerilog. However if your port type cannot be a vector, such as `integer` or `time` then you would need to use this method.